# How to configure custom 403 view in Laravel 4

Tags: php, apache, laravel, http-status-code-403

Currently I got set the error pages on start/global.php as it is recommended in Laravel docs.

Here is the code:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    if ( ! Config::get('app.debug'))
    {
        $view = (View::exists("error/{$code}")) ? "error/{$code}" : "error/404";
        return Response::view($view);
    }
}
```

where my views are

```
app/views/error/*
```

I have successfully tested 503, 500 and 400 but error page 403 is showing default apaches default as shown in the image:

[image]

Not sure why this is happening

Probably I testing 403 page the wrong way...
I know that I can test page 403 if run App::abort(403), but I'm looking for a way to verify its working on a real case.

Maybe I got an Apache configuration that's crashing with Laravel custom error pages?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument) doesn't allow targeting outside `DocumentRoot` so your only option is to use an [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias).

Add the following line to `.htaccess` inside your `public` folder.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.blade.php
```

and the following line to your `VirtualHost` definition (`Alias` is not allowed in `.htaccess`)

```
Alias /errors/ /path/to/resources/views/errors/
```

Comment: This could work if it did not cause an infinitive loop

Comment: A loop indicates a problem with Apache configuration. Set log level for `mod_rewrite` to at least `trace3` (`LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3`) and check the logs after that.

Answer (score 0):

Give permissions to img folder `chmod -R 0765 img`

Comment: Privileges on folder are not the case, what I need to do, is personalize 403 page, as I mention before 404, 500 and 503 custom pages are working as they should, but 403 is still showing apache default 403 error.